# WinEdt highliting switch: how to skip nested STOP symbol?

Tags: latex, syntax-highlighting

I have created a highlighting switch in WinEdt8 as following:

```
SWITCH="\REVR{?}"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TeX;BibTeX;MetaPost"
  START="{"
  STOP="}"
  HIGHLIGHT_START=0
  STEP_OVER_STOP=1
  HIGHLIGHT_STOP=0
  SCOPE=4
  DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=9
  INDENTED=0
  BOLN_ONLY=0
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  START1_TRIGGER="\REVR"
  START2_TRIGGER=""
  STOP1_TRIGGER=""
  STOP2_TRIGGER=""
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
    ITALIC=0
    TEXT_COLOR="#FF0000"
```

Since the STOP symbol is "}", the scope of this switch ends even if we have nested group "{}", like shown in the picture below:

[image: example]

How to make WinEdt to highlight all the text inside `\REVR{...}`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Switches.ini a custom definition must be placed before the "generic" one AND it should have the same (or lesser) priority than the generic one. In my case it was enough to move it on top of the file and change priority to 5.